# Wordpress Connect with facebook and other social media

Tags: wordpress, facebook-login

I am running [My Wordpress Powered Website](http://ckbbd.co.nf) on a free hosted platform and the provider blocked PHP curl extension. I want to let visitors login with facebook and other social platforms. I tried with some wordpress plugins (e.g: nextend facebook connect, social connect etc.) But, those plugins requires curl extension to work. Is there any alternatives to activate facebook, twitter connect in my wordpress website for login?

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found this, but it might be outdated, you can check if it works for you

http://martinsikora.com/facebook-php-api-without-curl-extension